# Как добавить Unit Test в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, юнит-тесты

Всем привет. Подскажите, кто знает, как добавить unit test, написаный на с# в проект юнити в Editor tests runner?

Comment: Тесты в Unity делаются как-то [так](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NdJXiYRy2Y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще все просто.

Допустим есть класс

```
public class MyTestClass {

    public int HP = 100;

    public void DecreaseHP(int value) {    
        HP -= value;
    }
}
```

В папке `Assets` создаем папку `Editor` (если её еще у вас нет). Все файлы с тестами должны находится именно в папке `Editor`, либо в её дочерхних директориях.

Чтобы создать файл теста на папке `Editor` нажимаем <kbd>ПКМ</kbd> и выбираем либо
`Create` → `C# Script` (длинный путь), либо `Create` → `Editor Test C# Script`

Если добавили скрипт вторым вариантом, то Юнити сгенерирует уже класс так, как он должен быть. Если нет, то надо знать, что

- необходимо подключить пространство имен для тестов `using NUnit.Framework;`
- все методы тестирования надо помечать атрибутом `[Test]`

Еще можно указывать атрибуты тестирования для класса, например `[TestFixture]`, но это зависит от...

Итак, минимальный класс для теста выглядит так:

```
using UnityEngine;    
using NUnit.Framework;

public class NewEditorTest {

    [Test]
    public void SomeMethod() {

    }
}
```

В принципе этого достаточно, чтоб он появился в *Unit Test Runner*. Нажимаем 
`Window` → `Unit Test Runner` и смотрим. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

Тест выглядит примерно так:

```
// Имя метода желательно чтоб отражало, что проверяем, и каков результат ожидаем
public void DecreaseHP_DescriptionOfWhatMethodWhouldDo() {
    var myTestClass = new MyTestClass();
    myTestClass.HP = 10;
    myTestClass.DecreaseHP(2);

    // проверяем, что после манипуляций у нас значения совпадают
    Assert.AreEqual(8, myTestClass.HP);
}
```